# ASP.NET Ajax PopupControlExtender On Close event?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, popupcontrolextender

I have a text box with an associated popupcontrolextender.This opens a panel containing a checkboxlist.

What i want to do is add the values selected in the checkbox list to the text box when the user clicks out of the panel.

I started to use the OnselectedIndexChanged, of the checkboxlist, and update the text box after every checkbox has been checked / unchecked. But the checkboxlist is quite long and when you click one of the checkboxes near the bottom, because everything is in an update panel, the checkboxlist scrolls to the top after the autopostback - not very user-friendly.

Any ideas???

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to stop this behavior:

> But the checkboxlist is quite long and when you click one of the checkboxes near the bottom, because everything is in an update panel, the checkboxlist scrolls to the top after the autopostback

Would that work better? Here's an oldie but a goodie article:

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020140248/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/111704-1.aspx